# Is possible to cast directly .ts (transport stream) live url?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, chromecast, android-tv

I have direct url of .ts https://urllink/stream/channel_id.ts
When I try to start casting to receiver application, it try to play media but nothing.Here is my code of sender android app:

```
    MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(channelCurrent.getUrl())
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
            //.setContentType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MP4)
            .setContentType("video/MP2T")
            .setMetadata(channelMetadata)
```

As you can see I tried to put different content types ( like M3u8 etc..) but not successful.

Can I create custom receiver application for play directly .ts live stream or some workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

-------------------kindly chak is your chore wersion browser and also counter you have official install chromcast in your reciver appliance fron play store with the same account which is login on yor main androida core home

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).